# Why do the Torus and the Klein Bottle have the same Euler characteristic and aren't homeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Isn't the Euler Characteristic a topological invariant?

Comment: If X and Y are homeomorphic, then they have the same Euler characteristic. The converse is not true

Comment: Such a homeomorphism would embed the Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Euler characteristic along with orientability is enough for distinguishing homeomorphism classes of closed surfaces.  One might say that homology theory was developed to figure out how to combine these into a single invariant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Euler's characteristic is a topological invariant, namely two homeomorphic spaces have the same Euler's characteristic but is not a **total** topological invariant. It does not suffice that two topological spaces have the same Euler's characteristic to ensure they are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 5):

We can make a lot of examples that illustrate this. It's a fact (which is not terribly hard to prove) that puncturing a surface decreases the Euler characteristic by $1$. The torus, for example, has Euler characteristic $0$. The sphere on the other hand has Euler characteristic $2$. If I puncture the sphere in two points, I get something which homotopy equivalent to a circle, yet a torus is most certainly not homotopy equivalent to a circle.

Since they aren't even homotopy equivalent, they certainly can't be homeomorphic!